# Mysql pivot table (concat) misuse (processing time)

Tags: mysql, pivot-table

I want to pivot the example below, I'm using:

```
SELECT Person, GROUP_CONCAT( Var ) , GROUP_CONCAT( Val ) 
FROM table
GROUP BY Person
```

This works fine, but... it takes about 20 seconds per line and my table has +/- 2.500.000 records :-P
(BTW; the table below is an example, not the actual one)

```
id person    Var    Val
-------------------------------
1  Bob       Height  185
2  Bob       Weight  74
3  Bob       Age     40
4  Hank      Height  193
5  Hank      Weight  90
6  Hank      Age     45
7  Bert      Height  180
8  Bert      Weight  85
9  Bert      Age     43
```

PS:
Besides an answer (what would make you awesome) I also would like to know what is 'wrong' with this example (makes you even more awesomer)

Comment: Do you really want to run the query on the entire table? Do you have any conditions to reduce the result set?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with it, except that I'd write it like this

```
SELECT Person, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(Var, ': ', Val))
FROM table
GROUP BY Person
```

because when you split it up in two columns, you won't know which `Val` belongs to which `Var`.

Apart from that, do you have indexes defined on those columns? If not, play around to see which index works best, separate indexes for each column or compound indexes on person, var, val.